# How can I get my Chrome-synced bookmarks in an Android device?

Tags: sync, browser, bookmarks

I'm using Google Chrome and syncing the bookmarks with the built-in feature. How can I get those bookmarks in my Android device?

Comment: Great question! Never thought of looking for an answer until you asked the question ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Synchronizing bookmarks between the Android browser and your Chrome desktop browser is now a built-in feature of Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0).

Comment: It should also work with Honeycomb, though seems to be buggy http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18937

Answer (score 5):

According to [this  answer by goblinbox:](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/25512/96277)

> The Dolphin mobile browser is supposed to have built-in Google Bookmarks sync capability.

An alternative would be to use GoMarks

> GoMarks is a application that helps
>   you sync and manage your bookmarks
>   with Google Bookmarks. Ideal solution
>   if you on desktop use Google Toolbar,
>   GMarks or any other Google Bookmarks
>   tools.
>
> Features:
>
> - Background sync
> - Labels
> - Use Menu->More->Share page to add new bookmark from Android browser

As Dan Herbert mentions:

> There is currently no way to do this natively. [Android's bug tracker has an open issue for this.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2907)

Comment: I would add to this answer the link to the Android bug database that is in another answer. I'm not going with any of these solutions and howe it's solved in Android sometime in this century, but I believe this is still the more complete answer for someone looking for a solution. Marking it as accepted.

Comment: Updated @J. Pablo Fernández, sorry to hear none of these things worked out for you...

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to do this natively. Android's bug tracker has an open issue for this.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2907

Answer (score 4):

As noted [here](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=100215), the bookmark sync used in Chrome is separate from Google Bookmarks.  The app that Ivo Flipse suggests works only for google bookmarks.

There is an app (which I haven't tried) that seems to allow access to Chrome bookmarks called ChromeMarks, but it isn't free.

The way that I access my bookmarks is through google docs: go to **docs.google.com**, at the bottom of the page select **My Folders**, then select the folder that has the bookmarks you want.  If you want to make access to this page easier, you can bookmark it in the mobile browser and put a shortcut on your homescreen.

This will get me by until it is built into the system (see Dan Herbert's post for more on that).

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

- [Xmarks](https://xmarks.com/) Premium (1$/month)
- [Google Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) for Android (only for Android 4.0/ICS or higher), syncs Bookmarks for the Desktop Chrome versions via the Google Account