# Can I sync my Chrome bookmarks with my Android phone?

Tags: browser, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I sync the bookmarks in the web browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1452/how-can-i-sync-the-bookmarks-in-the-web-browser)

Since I'm a big Google user, I'm used to everything ([Google Contacts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Contacts), etc.) being synchronised on my Android phone. Is it possible to use something similar to Chrome's bookmark synchronisation, but somehow get these bookmarks to my Android phone?

Comment: I'm not sure if this help You but there is delicio.us app for Android.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Dolphin mobile browser is supposed to have built-in Google Bookmarks sync capability.

Comment: Have not tested, but I assume this will work.

Comment: Does not sync with the bookmarks as stored by Google Chrome, but with the older Google bookmark service on goggle.com/bookmarks (Chrome stores bookmarks in Google Docs)

Comment: err, that should have been google.com/bookmarks (mobile typing..)

Comment: I didn't see that... neither to google.com/bookmarks nor to chrome bookmarks (google docs based) How can I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a number of ways to sync bookmarks to your Android phone.
If you're looking for one-click-import, check out the [MyBookmarks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dant.MyBookmarks) app for Android.

If you use Opera on your desktop, I think it lets you save your bookmarks on the cloud. You can then sync it to Android using Opera Mobile/Mini (i.e., if you use it as your primary browser)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox, you might want to take a look at Firefox 4 and [Firefox 4 Mobile](http://www.mozilla.com/mobile). Both have [Firefox Sync](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox_Sync) built-in, syncing bookmarks and browser history across various desktop installations of Firefox as well as on your mobile.

It's enough of a killer feature and done well enough that I've stopped using the stock Android 2.2 browser.

Answer (score 1):

I use Chrome on my computer, and Opera on my Android. So I installed Opera on my computer, opened Chrome's Bookmark Manager, exported bookmarks to a Chrome HTML document, started up Opera on the computer, imported Firefox bookmarks (no Chrome option, but Firefox option works), then synced to my Android's Opera. I'm assuming you could do the same for most browsers.