# 2.3.55: How can I edit Bookmarks between my Android phone and Desktop easily under Google account and Chrome?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, bookmarks, chrome-for-android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my Chrome-synced bookmarks in an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/483/how-can-i-get-my-chrome-synced-bookmarks-in-an-android-device)

I use Android -phone with my Google account. My laptop is configured for the same account. I would like to be able easily configure bookmarks: edit them, remove them, organize them, etc -- how can I do it over my phone and destop? Actually I have also iPad with Google Chrome so how can I edit them easily in one place? I can easily edit bookmarks with Bookmarks -manager `SHIFT+CTRL+O` in desktop but how easily in Android?

*I use Android 2.3.5, not 4.x that has this feature as default.*

Comment: @roxan thank you for the link, I implicitly assumed that you have bookmarks under your phone and desktop. Now I am trying to edit them, different question. I use ChromeMarks in Android but I am able to change any time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special method to do so, simply connect all your chrome browser across all you devises with same google account, and make change in any of the device and it should reflects and sync all other devises  and your **google account's dashboard->chrome** data also.

Comment: where is `google account's dashboard->chrome`?